# How to create a video calling function with swiftUI?

Tags: webrtc, swiftui

I am creating a messaging app with SwiftUI, and I want to add video calling function to that. I used SkyWay webRTC API (https://webrtc.ecl.ntt.com/en/) to achieve this and I could build an example project written in swift code. Now what I am trying is linking local stream with SKWVideo view and wrapping it up into UIViewRepresentable. But I got stuck with bellow error message.

```
import SwiftUI
import SkyWay
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var video = SKWVideo()

    var body: some View {
        VideoView(localStreamView: $video)
    }
}

struct VideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var localStreamView: SKWVideo

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKWVideo {
        let option: SKWPeerOption = SKWPeerOption.init()
        option.key = "xxxx"
        option.domain = "localhost"
        let peer = SKWPeer(options: option)
        SKWNavigator.initialize(peer!)
        let constraints: SKWMediaConstraints = SKWMediaConstraints()
        let localStream = SKWNavigator.getUserMedia(constraints)
        localStream?.addVideoRenderer(localStreamView, track: 0)
        return localStreamView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKWVideo, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}
```

I got this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
```

I ran it on a iPhone 7 real device, and I wrote plist settings. I have completely no idea right now. Please help me..

iOS 13.0
xcode 11.0

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Some code is modifying a state - `video` in this case - outside of the main thread. Given the nature of the library you're using, it may be expected or just a programming error. I would thoroughly check its documentation and see where it's happening.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hint. Yes.. But I don't know how to fix it. SKWVideo is a custom view inherited from UIView, so I thought I could follow the implementation of MKMapView like in the Apple's swiftUI tutorials. Here is the link for iOS SDK (https://webrtc.ecl.ntt.com/en/ios-sdk.html) and there is an example code of Swift at the bottom of the page. If you know how to achieve video messaging with SwiftUI in other ways, it would be very helpful for me...

Comment: What if you put `localStream?.addVideoRenderer(localStreamView, track: 0)` inside the `updateUIView(...)` method?